Deserialize a .NET HealthReport object
I am trying to deserialize a HTTP response message into a HealthReport object. However, neither Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json support deserializing to the type because cannot be a parameterless construction.
Since HealthReport is a widely used type for ASP.NET Core regarding Health Checks, I would assume that deserialization would be possible without elaborate custom JsonConvert functions. But I can't seem to make it work.
I call an endpoint which returns a HttpResponseMessage which I know only consists of a HealthReport.
I invoke ReadAsStringAsync() on that response. I try to deserialize with both NewtonSoft and System.Text.Json but both are throwing an exception that conversion is not supported because HealtReport does not support parameterless construction.
Does anybody have experience or suggestions to easily deserialize the content, it will I have to manually write a custom JsonConverter to achieve my desired result?

Welcome to the SO, please read [ask] and provide a [mre] so it would be easier to help you.

Can you explain what you mean when you say "neither NewtonSoft or System.Text.Json support deserializing to the type because cannot be a parameterless construction"? Are you deserializing the JSON response or are you creating a new class instance?

There's no reason you can't just deserialize like this var h = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HealthReport>(str);

@A-Fairooz OP seems to be trying to deserialize JSON into HealthReport class and having problems with it.

@JakobKaae what are you trying to do? Output customization is described in the docs. The docs also explain that The health checks API doesn't provide built-in support for complex JSON return formats because the format is specific to your choice of monitoring system. Prometheus for example expects a specific format and that's available through customization

@A-Fairooz Yes, I am trying to derserialize the the JSON response to the specified type like: var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(responseString, new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)).
That call throws this error: "Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported." Same goes when using NewtonSoft for deserialization.

@PanagiotisKanavos I am not trying to customize the ouput. Instead I just want to deserialize the JSON reponse and parse that along in order to store it my MongoDB. The idea is to monitor for bad health in my microservices from a Manager/Gateway and store it whenever a bad health is detected in a service. I call a healthcheck endpoint on a service which provides the HealthReport as JSON. I want to deserialize that and be able to attach a Guid and store it.

Accoding to your description I cannot verify if there is errors . There is no need for JsonConverter, you could try deserializing the JSON into an object that reflects the structure of the JSON , and then manually map that to a HealthReport object.

I received some good suggestions.
I ended up utilizing a custom converter and using a dynamic type as the target type for deserialization and then in a foreach loop, iterating over each property and mapping them to suitable types and instatiating a new HealthReport object based on the mapped properties.

I had the same issue. The HealthReport class is sealed, doesn't have an empty parameter constructor, and its properties only have get methods. Nothing conducive to deserialization.
After some grumbling about sending an http response as "application/json" that's not deserializable: I built a utility class to facilitate deserialization, then used a ToHealthReport method to get a HealthReport object.
public class SerializableHealthReport
{

    public Dictionary<string, HealthReportEntry> Entries { get; set; }
    public HealthStatus Status { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TotalDuration { get; set; }

    public SerializableHealthReport()
    {
    }

    public HealthReport ToHealthReport()
    {
        return new HealthReport(Entries, Status, TotalDuration);
    }
}

Example deserialization:
public HealthReport DeserializeHealthResponse(string httpResponseContent)
{
    var serializableHealthReport =
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SerializableHealthReport>(httpResponseContent);

    return serializableHealthReport.ToHealthReport();

}

I hope this helps!
